# How to run more than one application in blackberry jde4.5

Tags: blackberry

I wanted to create more than one application run simultaneously in Blackberry JDE4.5 can any one help me how to do it.

Comment: Um, if I understand your question, you simply create a new project in your workspace and code your application.

Answer (score 3):

With the JDE all Active projects in your workspace will be automatically built (and deployed to the simulator when you debug).  To see a list of Active projects, pick Set Active Projects from the Project menu in the JDE.  You can also activate/deactivate projects by right clicking on them in the tree.